# How to properly plot using multiple functions and set the linestyles?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote a scientific package which has a lot of different plotting functions which calculate data and then make a plot. I often want to plot several curves in one figure, and I'm not sure how to properly handle this. The code could look like this:

```
plot_temperature_graph_of_day(day='Monday')
plot_temperature_graph_day(day='Tuesday')
plot_week_mean_temperature()
plot_temperature_graph_of_several_days(('Wednesday','Thursday'))
```

The point is that I want to set the linestyle for each of these plots - the first three functions generate one plot each, the fourth one generates two. All of the go into the same figure. To set the style, I could

- Give each function an argument 'linestyle', which it would give to the `pyplot.plot` function
- Return the Line2D objects and set the linestyles using `setp`
- Don't let the functions to any plotting and just return the data
- Supply a callback function which does the actual plotting

Do you have any recommendations on the strategy?

Comment: why don't you let your users specify `*args` and/or `**kwargs` which you'd then forward to the plotting primitives, *and* return an line (or even an axis) instance in case they want to tweak it further?

Comment: This sounds good. Is this a common practice or something you figured out for yourself?

Comment: Don't know how common of a practice this is, would be interested to hear more educated opinions. My personal take is that it's best to both give a user a sensible default and all access to the guts, in case they are ready to take risks.

Comment: 1) What would be the advantage of returning an axis? 2) If you write an answer, I can accept it and vote on it :)

Comment: there you are. Sorry for a typo, I meant an `axes` instance, not just an 'axis'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a user perspective, my personal preference is to have a sensible default, and an access to the insides of a package, so that I can tweak things, if I really need or want to.

In this particular case, you're adding user-friendly functionality on top of matplotlib. Thus, by not giving a user access to line instances, you're also hiding some functionality of the base package, and that, in my opinion, is (almost) always a bad thing. Since matplotlib itself offers a whole bunch of useful `*args` and `**kwargs`, there should be a reason not to accept them in your functionality and just forwarding them to an underlying plotting routines. If a user supplies a nonsense arguments, it's their problem, not yours --- while you can try catching the exceptions raised by the plotting engine if you wish.

Moreover, if you return not just a line, but the complete `axes` instance, you might be saving a lot of sweat of a poor grad student somewhere, who's been ordered by her boss to add a grid onto the plot.